# tfs command line 'merge' equivalent in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, tfs-sdk

**EDIT**: poor wording of my question. What I am trying to achieve is to 'discard' the merge history of the changeset

**EDIT 2**
I worked out how I can remove the changeset from the merge candidate queue. I don't particularly think it is a good idea but I am including the code simply for 'completeness' sake.

SCENARIO: developer fixes bug on branch and checks in. Developer then fixes bug on trunk instead of merging (trunk has changed dramatically therefore not merging). However the changeset appears in the list when merging from the branch to the trunk. I am trying to mark this changeset to remove it from this list. This can be done using the commandline utility by passing the 'discard' switch...I am tryinh to achive the same using the TFS API..

I think I am pretty close by use of the Merge method but am not sure of the options to pass in. I do NOT want to perform a merge just want to mark the changeset as merged without merging

have got a list of changesets from TFS using a Winforms app and would like be able to merge a changeset by calling discard on it using C#

the merge command is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

can this be done using the TFS .NET libraries or do I have to call the commandline editor from the winforms app?

```
//get the merge candidates
IEnumerable<MergeCandidate> mergeCandidates =
                _vcs.GetMergeCandidates(cboSource.Text, cboTarget.Text, RecursionType.Full)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Changeset.ChangesetId)
                    .AsEnumerable();


//user select a changeset from a grid and then I want to discard this changeset from the //'merge list'

 string _changeset = grdChangeSets.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            VersionSpec vfrom = VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec(_changeset, null);
            VersionSpec vto = VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec(_changeset,null);
            _workspaces[0].Merge(cboSource.Text, cboTarget.Text, vfrom, vto, LockLevel.None, RecursionType.Full,
                                 MergeOptions.AlwaysAcceptMine);
```

**EDIT 2 CODE**

```
string _changeSetId = grdChangeSets.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();


            VersionSpec vfrom = VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec(_changeSetId, null);
            VersionSpec vto = VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec(_changeSetId, null);


            UsiWorkspace wksp = new UsiWorkspace();
            wksp.ResolveConflicts(_workspaces[0]);

            GetStatus getStatus = _workspaces[0].Merge(cboSource.Text,
                cboTarget.Text, 
                vfrom, 
                vto, 
                LockLevel.None, 
                RecursionType.Full, 
                MergeOptions.AlwaysAcceptMine);


var _conflicts = workspaces[0].QueryConflicts(null, true);
            foreach (Conflict conflict in _conflicts)
            {
                conflict.Resolution = Resolution.DeleteConflict;
                workspace.ResolveConflict(conflict);
            }



            var wip = new WorkspaceCheckInParameters(_workspaces[0].GetPendingChanges(),string.Format("CHECKED IN FROM TFS TOOL - {0} {1}", DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString(), Environment.UserName))
                {

                    OverrideGatedCheckIn = ((CheckInOptions2) _vcs.SupportedFeatures & CheckInOptions2.OverrideGatedCheckIn) ==
                        CheckInOptions2.OverrideGatedCheckIn,
                    PolicyOverride = new PolicyOverrideInfo("CHECKED IN FROM TFS TOOL - POLICY", null)
                };

            _workspaces[0].CheckIn(wip);
```

Comment: Do you have any code?

Answer (score 3):

There is a merge method in the TFS api : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731634.aspx

Perhaps something like this :

```
var status = _workspace.Merge(sourceTfsPath, targetTfsPath, null, null, LockLevel.None, RecursionType.Full,
    MergeOptions.AlwaysAcceptMine);
Trace.WriteLine(status.NumOperations);
var conflicts = _workspace.QueryConflicts(null, true);
foreach (var conflict in conflicts)
{
    conflict.Resolution = Resolution.AcceptYours;
    _workspace.ResolveConflict(conflict);
}
```

Comment: this seems to be the answer except that I can't see how I can 'discard'

Comment: thanks Philippe - I have not worded the original question very well. I am trying to discard the changeset. The fix has been implemented manually without the need for merging and I just want to mark the history of the changeset as discarded so that it does not popup in the list any more. I will edit my question and include some code. I think your answer is definitely heading the right way

Comment: I better understand your problem and have no good solution for it. Perhaps the good way to do it is to create a fix branch from a changeset common to all the branches, containing only your bug fix and merge this branch with your trunk and your dev branch. This way, you should not annoyed when merging your dev branch in your trunk...

Comment: thanks for your help. I found a way to get the changeset of the merge candidates list using a merge  followed by checkin. I'll edit the OP to include the code. Personally I don't think what I have done is a good idea but I was asked to investigate and try and come up with a solution for the team. I'll present that to the team as well. Thanks again